# Meteor template wrong data-* on second click. Is this a bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, meteor

This is also an opened issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4231

**Short story**

Here you can see a demo of the problem (press some times ADD and then the first X many times.. Only the first one will delete the record. Then try with the second button for the very same issue): 
http://bug-event-template.meteor.com

Here the source code: https://github.com/brugnara/meteor-bug-event-template

**Long story**

I have a template that renders an array of objects stored in `Session`.

You can try by your self. You press the ADD button and you will see a list of items with a red sign that is supposed to remove the current item, and it works the first time you press it. The second time I get an error saying the id doesn't exist. With the inspector, I can see the `data-id=RAND` and it is right. The only wrong thing is the result of the `.data('id')` function the second time I press the button. I really can't understand what is happening. May this be a bug somewhere? (see the ***** signed comment. The value obtained is wrong but anything else is rendered ok, ie the DEBUG `{{id}}` is showing correctly and the inspector shows the data-id setted correctly. In my opinion the `event` routine fails at some point, or simply I'm making some issue with the code :) )

Thank you for the attention.

Manager:

```
var MESSAGE_QUERIES = 'messages:queries';
var MESSAGE_CURRENT = 'messages:current';

Template.messagesNew.helpers({
  queries: function() {
    return Session.get(MESSAGE_QUERIES);
  }
});

Template.messagesNew.events({
  'keyup #message-new-text': function(e) {
    var $len = $('#message-new-text-length');
    var $text = $(e.target);
    var len = $text.val().length;
    $len.html(len === 0 ? '' : len + (len === 1 ? ' char' : ' chars'));
  },

  'click .query-add': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = chance.word({ length:16 });
    var queries = Session.get(MESSAGE_QUERIES);
    if (!queries) {
      queries = [];
    }
    queries.push({
      id: id
    });
    Session.set(MESSAGE_QUERIES, queries);
  },

  'click .btn-remove': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var $target = Template.instance().$(e.currentTarget);
    var id = $target.data('id'); // ************* This is wrong any click but first
    TARGET = $target; // for debug only
    var queries = Session.get(MESSAGE_QUERIES);
    var toRemove = -1;
    $target.blur();
    //
    queries.forEach(function(query, index) {
      if (query.id === id) {
        toRemove = index;
      }
    });
    if (toRemove === -1) {
      return console.warn('Nothing found with id:', id);
    }
    console.log('Removing query with id:', id, 'in position:', toRemove);
    queries.splice(toRemove, 1);
    Session.set(MESSAGE_QUERIES, queries);
  }
});
```

Template

```
<template name="messagesNew">

  <form>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message-new-text">Text message</label>
      <small class="pull-right" id="message-new-text-length"></small>
      <textarea id="message-new-text" class="form-control" placeholder="Lorem ipsum"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Queries</label>
      <button class="btn btn-default query-add">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        Add
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      {{#each queries}}
        DEBUG: {{id}}
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-title">
            <div>
              <span class="pull-right query-remove">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-remove" id="query-remove-{{id}}" data-id="{{id}}">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove disabled" style="margin-top: 3px;"></span>
                </button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            {{>query .}}
          </div>
        </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>

  </form>

</template>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using Meteor in the wrong way. You should understand the data context you are in. 
With `{{#each queries}}` you set the data context of the loop to each element.
So within your event `'click .btn-remove'` you should be able to fetch the id directly with `this.id` instead of using data attributes. Like this:

```
{{#each queries}}
  <div>
    ...
    <div class="btn-remove">X</div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

And in the template event:

```
Template.messagesNew.events({
  'click .btn-remove': function(e) {
    var queryId = this.id; //get the current item id with this.id

    //then do whatever you want based on the queryId you got
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks for sharing. With this I can workaround the problem but it doesn't explain why the second click jQuery gives me wrong data.

Comment: I think it is because the data function only gather the data attributes contents at the first load of the DOM. If you want subsequent updates of data attributes you should set the values directly with the data function

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. In fact, reloading the whole page (CMD+R) everything works well.